# masonry jquery adding divs

Tags: jquery, masonry

The code is at http://codepen.io/soap262/pen/XbEeXm.  The problematic part is

```
$('.grid').append(gridItemDivs1);
$('.group1').css("background-color", "blue");

$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 160,
  gutter: 20
});

$('.grid').append(gridItemDivs2);
$('.group2').css("background-color", "orange");
$('.grid').masonry();
```

The first set of grid-item divs are processed correctly by masonry, but it seems to never touch the second set.  Desandro's documentation at http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html is very nicely done, but I'm still missing something.  What is it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should call masonry appended method in your second block of code:

```
$('.grid').append(gridItemDivs1);
$('.group1').css("background-color", "blue");

$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 160,
  gutter: 20
});

$('.group2').css("background-color", "orange");
$('.grid').masonry('appended', gridItemDivs2);
```

Comment: I believe that last line is what is missing in the OP. You gotta tell masonry items have been appended and that's the same for their Packery library which I have been playing with for the last couple days.

Comment: Thanks for the lead, but I'm afraid it didn't work.  I also tried $('.grid').masonry('reloadItems'), but that simply stacked the orange divs in the top left corner of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around on another question: [Masonry - Divs stack correctly only once on each page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255568/masonry-divs-stack-correctly-only-once-on-each-page-load).  The second set of divs will load properly if masonry is first destroyed, and then reinitialized, including all parameters:

```
$('.grid').masonry('destroy');
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 160,
  gutter: 20
});
```

The documentation makes it clear that masonry should be able to process updates, so this is not the ideal solution.